# Silverstripe 4 UploadField additional Formfield

Tags: post, file-upload, textfield, silverstripe

With Silverstripe 4 how can i have an UploadField(Extension) and an additional FormField (e.g. TextField) and get the value of this TextField via POST in the function upload when uploading a file?

```
class UploadFieldExtension extends UploadField
```

private static $allowed_actions = [
'upload'
];

```
public function upload(HTTPRequest $request, $dummyCategory = null)
{
    
    $tmpFile = $request->postVar('Upload');
    $file = $this->saveTemporaryFile($tmpFile, $error);
    $folder = Folder::find_or_make('Products');

    // Create the product object and set its properties
    $product = ProductObject::create();
    $product->Title = $file->Title;
    $product->ProductImage = $file;
    $product->ProductImageID = $file->ID;
    $product->ProductCatObjectID = ''; //$dummyCategoryValue;
    $id = $product->write();

    $file->ProductObjectID = $id;
    $file->ProductSettingID = '';
    $fileID = $file->write();
    $file->doPublish();

    $myimage = MyImage::create();
    $myimage->ImageID = $fileID;
    $myimage->ProductObjectID = $id;
    $myimage->write();
    $myimage->doPublish();
        
    // Prepare result
    if ( $error ) {
        $result = [
            'message' => [
                'type' => 'error',
                'value' => $error,
            ]
        ];
        $this->getUpload()->clearErrors();
        return ( new HTTPResponse( json_encode( $result ), 400 ) )->addHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    }

    // We need an ID for getObjectFromData
    if ( !$file->isInDB() ) {
        $file->write();
    }

    // Return success response
    $result = [
        AssetAdmin::singleton()->getObjectFromData( $file )
    ];

    // Don't discard pre-generated client side canvas thumbnail
    if ( $result[ 0 ][ 'category' ] === 'image' ) {
        unset( $result[ 0 ][ 'thumbnail' ] );
    }
    $this->getUpload()->clearErrors();
    return ( new HTTPResponse( json_encode( $result ) ) )->addHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Extension", I assume you mean just a regular subclass, rather than [the Silverstripe CMS concept of Extensions](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/5/developer_guides/extending/extensions) - it's worth noting that when talking about Silverstripe CMS code, an "Extension" is a specific concept, unrelated to subclass inheritance.

As for your actual question - the short answer is that whatever you're trying to do will probably be easier to do *after* the upload. The `UploadField` uploads files asynchronously to the form submission. You'd need to implement your own logic to bypass that initial upload, and instead include the file in the actual form submission itself.

You could use a `FileField` which doesn't upload the file ahead of time - but assuming this is for use in the CMS rather than on the front-end, you'd still need to provide some javascript logic before the form submission to include the file field value in the form submission, since `<input type="file">` is excluded by default in the CMS form submissions (under the assumption you're probably using `UploadField`, not FileField`).

Long story short, without more information about your specific use case, I'm assuming it's going to be easier for you to add some logic to either `onAfterWite()` on the underlying `DataObject` the form belongs to, or to the relevant controller (if, for example, this is in a custom admin section).